# How random values considering the smallest and largest value of a specific column

Tags: r

How do I generate random values considering the smallest and largest value of column AB to insert into column `CB`. So it can be any value in the range from the lowest value to the highest value.

```
df<-structure(list(AB = c(23,252.23,111,2345.2,123.4), CB = c("", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

> df
       AB CB
1   23.00   
2  252.23   
3  111.00   
4 2345.20   
5  123.40
```

Comment: Do you want the column CB to only be able to take values that appear in AB or can it take any value between 23 and 2345?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may get the `range` of 'AB' and `sample` with `replace = TRUE` to fill the 'CB' column

```
df$CB <- sample(seq(min(df$AB), max(df$AB), by = 0.01), 
     length(df$AB), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @Akrun! It's more or less that, but in this case, it could be any value in the range of the smallest value, ie 23, and the largest value 2345.20 . I think I didn't make that clear in the question.

Comment: @Antonio As your column have some precision, what would the precision you expected in digits

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is at most two places after the comma.

Comment: @Antonio perhaps `sample(seq(min(df$AB), max(df$AB), by = 0.01), length(df$AB), replace = TRUE)`

Comment: A question @akrun, whenever I run your code I will generate random numbers. But if I want to generate only once, is it possible?

Comment: @Antonio If you are looking for a reproducible random number then use `set.seed` i.e. `set.seed(24); v1 <- sample(seq(min(df$AB), max(df$AB), by = 0.01), 
     length(df$AB), replace = TRUE);` and then you assign the object created to column i.e. `df$CB <- v1`